# How to format dates from a file containing different formats in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime, date-formatting

I have a excel file which has dates in multiple formats in no particular order.
The formats vary

```
dd/mm/yyyy
dd/mm/yy
dd.mm.yyyy
dd.mm.yy
dd-mm-yyyy
dd-mm-yy
dd.Jan.18
dd-Jan-2018
```

I loop through the excel rows and fetch the dates one by one. How can I convert these dates to a particular format?
Preferably yyyy-mm-dd
I'm using PHP and storing the dates into mysql after processing.

I have tried this method but it doesn't work for dd.mm.yy

```
$date = $row[$datepos];
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Are those all the formats you could encounter or are more variations possible?

Comment: Yes, only these.

Comment: Just [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) `.` and `-` with `/`

Comment: What if you add an extra row between row 2 and 3: `$date = str_replace('.', '-', $date);`

Comment: There are more formats edited in question.

Comment: A cell value doesn't depends on the cell format.

Comment: Is that the final list of date variations or will there be more in the future? The trouble with dates is that while your current list seems to actually be pretty uniform, there often are cases where dates are in the US format (mm-dd-yy) or in the Chinese format (yy-mm-dd), and that's when things get hairy.

Comment: Yes this is the historic data. So there will be no more date formats to look for in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are the *only* dates you have to deal with, the following code will work:

```
$dates = [
    "01/01/2018",
    "01/01/18",
    "01.01.2018",
    "01.01.18",
    "01-01-2018",
    "01-01-18",
    "01.Jan.18",
    "01-Jan-18",
];

foreach($dates as $date){
    $dt_array = preg_split("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $date);
    //Break apart the date string using any non-alphanumeric character as the delimiter

    var_dump($dt_array);
    //Just for demonstration purposes

    $day = $dt_array[0];
    // Grab the day

    if(is_numeric($dt_array[1])){
        $month = $dt_array[1];
    } else {
        $dp = date_parse($dt_array[1]);
        $month = $dp['month'];
    }
    //The month is a little bit more complex,
    //because at times it's an integer, at times it's a string,
    //and we want it to always be a integer

    $year = $dt_array[2];
    //Grab the year

    $dt = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-{$day}");
    //The y-m-d format is flexible,
    //because it will accept yyyy and yy
    //and since your m and d are integers,
    //it will work even if they don't have a leading zero.

    var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));
    //Just for demonstration purposes
}
```

Comment: Great! Just keep in mind this won't work for US format dates (mm/dd/yy).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

$date=date_create(pass the date from your excel);
date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");

Comment: Tried it, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'the' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in `

Comment: $array = array("-",".");
$date = str_replace($array,'/','10.12.2014');
$date = date_create($date);
echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d');
Output:2014-10-12 @kiran-g